# "Virtualization type 'hvm' required" error in Apache Brooklyn

Tags: brooklyn

I tried to create blueprint from chef  as per the link https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/yaml/chef/creating-blueprints.html .

The location and provisioning.properties for a large instance is provided through yaml.

But when I launch it , I get the following error:

```
Required entity not healthy: ChefEntityImpl{id=aL3U028F}Failure running task invoking
start[locations] on 1 node (Aw2cyO4I): Error invoking start at ChefEntityImpl{id=aL3U028F}:
org.jclouds.aws.AWSResponseException: request POST https://ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/
 HTTP/1.1 failed with code 400, error: AWSError{requestId='27baa951-42d1-424d-9bca-c97047207ac3',
requestToken='null', code='InvalidParameterCombination', message=**'Virtualization type
'hvm' is required for instances of type 't2.small'.',**
```

Brooklyn is picking up t2.small type of instance ignoring the provisioning.properties mentioned through yaml .

Is there a way to specify provision.properties via brooklyn.properties file  or force Brooklyn to override with the configuration provided via blueprint ?

Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You can follow this issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BROOKLYN-140, and in jclouds at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-889

Comment: The YAML blueprint at that link (https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/yaml/chef/creating-blueprints.html) does not include a provisioning.properties. Could you include the YAML for your blueprint please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. I am able to launch the chef blueprint by specifying ami Id as part of provisioning.properties. provisioning.properties: # this will override the properties minRam: 5046mb minCores: 4 minDisk: 1024 imageId: eu-west-1/ami-3bbaa54f And I had made a mistake in indentation . Kindly refer to gist.github.com/ahgittin/ef8a4b39695f6d4c684e for more details. Thanks for the help !